# How do i script button in google sheets to 'Jump to current date' automatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I have huge sheets full of numbers - i'm looking to create a button in google sheets which allows me to jump to todays date (the dates are in a column)

i know how to create a hyper link however i want to click a button instead of text - google sheets only allows you to add script to a button and not hyperlinks.

Does anyone know how to script a button in google sheets to automatically jump to the current date on the sheet?

Comment: Get all of the data for that column in an array.  Loop through the array until you find that button.  The used sheet.getRange(row number, col number).activate()

Comment: @Cooper I'm new to this - can you provide me with an example so can implement this into my work

Comment: If you provide me with an image of the sheet containing the data so that will know where the pertinent data is located.

Comment: As for the 'button'... a button (a drawing, in fact) is anchored on rows, it will be scrolled up if your date is somewhere far down and vice versa. I'd propose a custom menu to activate the function. Or, it can be done as a side panel but it probably will be overkill for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, here is the lite version (with a custom menu instead of a button):

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('️ Scripts')
    .addItem('Jump to current date', 'jump_to_current_date')
    .addToUi()
}

function jump_to_current_date() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dates = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getDisplayValues().flat();
  var date  = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
  var row   = dates.indexOf(date) + 1;

  if (row > 0) { sheet.getRange('A' + row).activate() }
  else { ss.toast('No current date was found') }
}
```

The code searchs for dates in column 'A' of the sheet 'Sheet1' and supposes that dates are formatted as '2021/11/30'. To run the script it creates the 'Custom menu':

[image]

Of course you can [draw a 'button'](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26326035/how-to-run-a-script-from-a-button-in-google-sheets?hl=en&msgid=26366917) to fire the function `jump_to_current_date()`, if it suits you.

Comment: Thank you very much Yuri - sadly i'm still struggling to get this to work please see my example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L_hfbznCC6JbW_rWZlIbjMacKGeZLbtQTBzaRdKGkYY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to change 'A' --> 'B' (everywhere) and "yyyy/MM/dd" --> "MM/dd/yy", then save and reload, and it should work on your sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L1Snb8Uu2hZDGtMlw2HNjMmClyxQ1y0dehRifIZFzK0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks yuri - my dates are actually dd/MM/yy also i had to change var row   = dates.indexOf(date) + 1; to plus 3 as it was 2 days off for whatever reason -- the script now works, thanks for your help

Comment: Dates are tricky beasts. +2 days? It's probably because the time zone offset. Nasty thing as well. I wouldn't surprised if you will have +1 or +2 offset tomorrow. Probably there should be `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` instead of `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` or something else. Let me know if you need a help

Answer (score 1):

#### Go to today's date

```
function gotoCurrentDate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();//might need to edit header row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dts = Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM dd, yyyy");//might want to change format
  const pos = { col: {}, idx: {} };
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { pos.col[h] = i + 1; pos.idx[h] = i; });
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[pos.idx['Date Column Header Name']]);
    let ds = Utilities.formatDate(d,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM dd, yyyy");//might wat to change format
    if(ds == dts) {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, pos.col['Data Column Header Name']  ).activate()
    }
  });
}
```

You can goto to [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) and using the search box find any function that you don't understand.

If it's a pure JavaScript function the go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

```
<input type="button" value="Go To Current Date" onClick="google.script.run.gotoCurrentDate();" />
```

Put this into the html of a sidebar and use below function to launch side break.  When you open an html file it will come with some html put this into the body and save it.

If you get more than one input controls you may like to have this in the head.

```
<style> input {margin: 1px 2px 1px 0};
```

gs:

```
function launchSideBar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar html file name. Do not include the extension').setTitle('Sidebar Title'))
}
```

Here's what the side bar I use on the spreadsheet I answer questions on looks like today:

[image]

You can use buttons right on the spreadsheet but personally I think that they are a PITA.